# Update an excel sheet on Windows server 2012 with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, windows-server-2012

I am writing an application where we need to update an existing Excel sheet through our system. I was able to do so on my local machine with ***OleDbConnection*** but when i deploy the application on server it gives me ***"operation must use an updateable query"***
error on Windows server 2012. 
I know its not recommended to install MS Office on Server and thats why its causing the issue. Any one has an idea whast the work around for this problem.

Do i have to give permission to my .net application so it can update the excel file or its something else?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I know its not recommended to install MS Office on Server

Last I checked, it is also a violation of the license terms (though that may have changed)

As you note, there are many reasons it is unwise to deploy Office to a server environment.

If you are using the newer (2007+) .xlsx file format exclusively, you can use the open source [EPPlus library](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) for most common Excel tasks.  It is free, straightforward to use, and is designed to work on a server.

> EPPlus is a .net library that reads and writes Excel 2007/2010 files using the Open Office Xml format (xlsx).